# Features and security of new GUI compared to the command line wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, security, monero-wallet-gui, features

For those that like the official command line wallet and are comfortable using it, is there any reason to switch to the GUI once released? Does the GUI contain any new features that the command line wallet does not?

For those that prefer to use graphical interfaces, are there any new security concerns associated with the GUI that do not exist with the command line interface alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GUI has a QR code display, and a "tracking" mode, where a merchant can setup a transaction (new payment id, a particular amount), let a customer scan the QR code, and detect when the matching payment is seen on the pool or the chain. This still needs software on the customer side which can read the QR code and automatically present a tx to send, which the GUI can't do yet.

The GUI can also start/stop the daemon, saving you a few keystrokes.

It doesn't have anything about cold wallet signing, however.